# Is it possible / what are examples of using hygienic macros for the compile time computational optimization?

Tags: optimization, macros, scheme, lisp

I've been reading through https://lispcast.com/when-to-use-a-macro, and it states (about clojure's macros)

> Another example is performing expensive calculations at compile time as an optimization

I looked up, and it seems clojure has unhygienic macros. Can this also be applied to hygienic ones? Particularly talking about Scheme. As far as I understand hygienic macros, they only transform syntax, but the actual execution of code is deferred until the runtime no matter what.

Comment: How does macros transform syntax, if them not executed? Simple Racket example: ``(define-syntax compile-time-compute (λ (stx) (with-syntax (((_ exp) stx)) #`(quote #,(eval-syntax #'exp)))))``, then when you write `(compile-time-compute (+ 1 2))` it will transform syntax to ``(quote 3)``.

Comment: @PetSerAl Wasn't aware about `with-syntax`; looking at it, it's supported in r6rs, but not in r7rs. But I suppose it (or it's equivalent in the specific implementation) is required for compile-time computation, right? I failed to do something similar with `syntax-rules`

Comment: `with-syntax` is only needed to unpack syntax object (`stx`) and to extract second list element (`exp`) from it. If you able to pass arbitrary `λ` form to `define-syntax`, then that form can represent arbitrary complex computation, which would happens in compile time. https://ideone.com/UUFOb7

Comment: Note that `(+ 2 2) and `4`  are just different syntax whose execution is deferred into run-time. We can transform one to the other at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  [Macro hygiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) just refers to whether or not macro expansion can accidentally capture identifiers.  Whether or not a macro is hygienic, regular macro expansion (as opposed to reader macro expansion) occurs at compile-time.  Macro expansion replaces the macro's code with the results of it being executed.  Two major use cases for them are to transform syntax (i.e. DSLs), to enhance performance by eliminating computations at run time or both.

A few examples come to mind:

1. You prefer to write your code with angles in degrees but all of the calculations are actually in radians.  You could have macros eliminate these trivial, but unnecessary (at run time) conversions, at compile time.
2. [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a broad example of compute optimization that macros can be used for.
3. You have a string representing a SQL statement or complex textual math expression which you want to parse and possibly even execute at compile time.

You could also combine the examples and have a memoizing SQL parser.  Pretty much any scenario where you have all the necessary inputs at compile time and can therefore compute the result is a candidate.

Comment: I don't think macro use for memoization is an optimization, since (as far as I understand) it could as well be implemented with a regular function; macro just makes it nicer to use

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Macro-generated memoization can actually inline together the memoization logic and the function body, so it's not just wrapping one function with another. Plus provide syntactic sugars like selecting which arguments serve as keys for the  memoization, and which kind of equality is used and such.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Memoization by function relies on mutable function bindings: we have some function G and we replace it with a new function which has a reference to the old G. When the old G recurses, it calls the memoized entry point as we want.  Under lexical scoping with imutable function bindings, we can't do this kind of trick; G calls itself no matter what.  Macros can generate you a lexically scoped function that is memoized, while looking much like a regular function definition.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino As an extension to what Kaz said, in CL for instance, a function *f* can assume that calls to *f* in its body are calls to itself, unless *f* is declared `notinline` (which must happen before it's compiled, obviously).  So such a function can *only* be memoized by use of a macro.  Mamoization-by-function works in languages like Python only because it has a very rudimentary compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hygienic macros can do this sort of thing.  As an example here is a macro called `plus` in Racket which is like `+` except that, at macroexpansion-time, it sums sequences of adjacent literal numbers.  So it does some of the work you might expect to be done at run-time at macroexpansion-time (so, effectively, at compile-time).  So, for instance

```
(plus a b 1 2 3 c 4 5)
```

expands to

```
(+ a b 6 c 9)
```

Some notes on this macro.

- It's probably not very idiomatic Racket, because I'm a mostly-unreformed CL hacker, which means I live in a cave and wear animal skins and say 'ug' a lot. In particular I am sure I should use `syntax-parse` but I can't understand it.
- It might not even be right.
- There are subtleties with arithmetic which means that this macro can return different results than `+`.  In particular `+` is defined to add pairwise from left to right, while `plus` does not in general: all the literals get added firsto in particular (assuming you have done (require racket/flonum, and `+max.0` &c have the same values as they do on my machine), then `(+ -max.0 1.7976931348623157e+308 1.7976931348623157e+308)` has a value of `1.7976931348623157e+308`, while `(plus -max.0 1.7976931348623157e+308 1.7976931348623157e+308)` has a value of `+inf.0`, because the two literals get added first and this overflows.
- In general this is a useless thing: it's safe to assume, I think, that any reasonable compiler will do these kind of optimisations for you.  The only purpose of it is to show that it's possible to do the detect-and-compile-away compile-time constants.
- Remarkably, at least from the point of view of caveman-lisp users like me, you can treat this just like `+` because of the last in the `syntax-case`: it works to say `(apply plus ...)` for instance (although no clever optimisation happens in that case of course).

Here it is:

```
(require (for-syntax racket/list))

(define-syntax (plus stx)
  (define +/stx (datum->syntax stx +))
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_)
     ;; return additive identity
     #'0]
    [(_ a)
     ;; identity with one argument
     #'a]
    [(_ a ...)
     ;; the interesting case: there's more than one argument, so walk over them
     ;; looking for literal numbers.  This is probably overcomplicated and
     ;; unidiomatic
     (let* ([syntaxes (syntax->list #'(a ...))]
            [reduced (let rloop ([current (first syntaxes)]
                                 [tail (rest syntaxes)]
                                 [accum '()])
                       (cond
                         [(null? tail)
                          (reverse (cons current accum))]
                         [(and (number? (syntax-e current))
                               (number? (syntax-e (first tail))))
                          (rloop (datum->syntax stx
                                                (+ (syntax-e current)
                                                   (syntax-e (first tail))))
                                 (rest tail)
                                 accum)]
                         [else
                          (rloop (first tail)
                                 (rest tail)
                                 (cons current accum))]))])
       (if (= (length reduced) 1)
           (first reduced)
           ;; make sure the operation is our +
           #`(#,+/stx #,@reduced)))]
    [_
     ;; plus on its own is +, but we want our one.  I am not sure this is right
     +/stx]))
```

---

It is possible to do this even more aggressively in fact, so that `(plus a b 1 2 c 3)` is turned into `(+ a b c 6)`.  This has probably even more exciting might-get-different answers implications.  It's worth noting what the CL spec [says about this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/12_aaa.htm):

> For functions that are mathematically associative (and possibly commutative), a conforming implementation may process the arguments in any manner consistent with associative (and possibly commutative) rearrangement. This does not affect the order in which the argument forms are evaluated [...]. What is unspecified is only the order in which the parameter values are processed. This implies that implementations may differ in which automatic coercions are applied [...].

So an optimisation like this is clearly legal in CL: I'm not clear that it's legal in Racket (although I think it should be).

```
(require (for-syntax racket/list))

(define-for-syntax (split-literals syntaxes)
  ;; split a list into literal numbers and the rest
  (let sloop ([tail syntaxes]
              [accum/lit '()]
              [accum/nonlit '()])
    (if (null? tail)
        (values (reverse accum/lit) (reverse accum/nonlit))
        (let ([current (first tail)])
          (if (number? (syntax-e current))
              (sloop (rest tail)
                     (cons (syntax-e current) accum/lit)
                     accum/nonlit)
              (sloop (rest tail)
                     accum/lit
                     (cons current accum/nonlit)))))))

(define-syntax (plus stx)
  (define +/stx (datum->syntax stx +))
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_)
     ;; return additive identity
     #'0]
    [(_ a)
     ;; identity with one argument
     #'a]
    [(_ a ...)
     ;; the interesting case: there's more than one argument: split the
     ;; arguments into literals and nonliterals and handle approprately
     (let-values ([(literals nonliterals)
                   (split-literals (syntax->list #'(a ...)))])
       (if (null? literals)
           (if (null? nonliterals)
               #'0
               #`(#,+/stx #,@nonliterals))
           (let ([sum/stx (datum->syntax stx (apply + literals))])
             (if (null? nonliterals)
                 sum/stx
                 #`(#,+/stx #,@nonliterals #,sum/stx)))))]
    [_
     ;; plus on its own is +, but we want our one.  I am not sure this is right
     +/stx]))
```